# View trace() result on iOS

Tags: ios, haxe, openfl

Where does haxe output when calling `trace()` on iOS? With Android, I can see what I've traced with logcat, and in the output panel of FlashDevelop on neko and flash. I've tried going through the console, but I can't find anything. `Sys.println()` doesn't seem to output to the console, either.

Comment: Perhaps you should create a text field and add log to it instead of `trace()`ing. And a toggle so you could make the text field visible/invisible

Comment: @DleanJeans Yeah I too think so, since I can't find anything about this. But isn't it weird, since `trace()` is supposed to be available on all platforms. Some haxe developers targeting iOS might bump into this in future, too.